# Ros Intallation Problem

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
Ros-hydro-desktop-full: Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158186/ros-intallation-problem/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-28**:
Can you provide more details? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-28**:
I also guess if the version of Ubuntu matches hydro. I'm sorry, but you set up your sources.list, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try aptitude instead of apt-get

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1